# Cakephp log all errors in production server

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I have gone through this link but it didn't help me.

[how do you log php errors with cakephp when debug is 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904306/how-do-you-log-php-errors-with-cakephp-when-debug-is-0)

I need to log all errors when the debug is 0. I am using cakephp2.0 . What settings I should give in core ? I tried with define('LOG_ERROR', 2); and made an error intentionally but it is not inserting into any log files under cake/app/tmp/logs folder.

And is this depends on php.ini settings ?

Comment: Works fine with me. You should update your message with php.ini settings related to error handling. Also, include more details with the error you are trying to catch.